# Assigning the clone of an instance to the base interface

Tags: c#, oop

Let's say :

```
public interface IBase
{
// Stuff
}

public class Derived : IBase
{
// Stuff
}
```

When doing

```
Derived instance_ = new CDrv(); 
Ibase ibase = instance_; // Line 1
```

is this an implicit conversion or an assignment?

Is it possible to produce a clone of `instance_` and assign/convert to `ibase` maybe by overriding conversion or assignment operator or some other method?

Or in other words is there any way to pass the `instance_` by value rather than making it struct? I do not want it to be a struct because I have a number of functions that return `Derived` and the above conversion/assignment will occur rarely.

Comment: Do you want a shallow or a deep copy?

Comment: @Martinho : Shallow copy would be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no implicit conversion that will clone the object.

You would need to make a mechanism that "clones" the object (potentially implementing [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx), though that interface is less than ideal), either via a method or a new constructor:

```
IBase ibase = new Derived(instance_); // Using "copy constructor" you create
```

Or:

```
IBase ibase = instance_.Clone(); // ie: implement ICloneable, or similar mechanism
```

Comment: +1 If you only need a shallow copy, take a look at Object.MemberwiseClone (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx)

Comment: Don't forget that because ICloneable is not generic, a cast will be required.

Comment: @Martinho: Which, of course, is just one of many disadvantages of using ICloneable.